# Electrical resistivity: the effect of adding electrons

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Consider a copper wire of fixed length and cross-sectional area, and apply an electric field to the wire induced by a fixed potential difference $V$ across the two endpoints of the wire. By Ohm's law, we know that the current intensity is given by $I = V/R$, where $R$ denotes the resistance of the wire.

I know that when an electric field is applied, the free electrons move inside the conduction band toward some direction depending on the sign of the electric field. They can do so because there is a lot of available electronic states near the Fermi level.

> What happens if we add extra free-to-move electrons to the wire?
>
> - In what way will the resistivity of the metal be affected?
> - Will the current intensity increase, decrease or remain the same?

I think that if the number of electrons inside the conduction band increases, there will be less available electronic states and the electron mobility will decrease. Further, I know that if the conduction band is entirely filled, the wire can no longer conduct electricity.

Comment: Contemplate how many electrons you would have to add to fill up the conduction band in the metal. Assuming you could do that, now calculate the potential energy from all the excess, uncompensated by nuclei, charge you've stuffed in there. Now think how $V$ will remain constant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metal conducts quite well because the there is an electron band that crosses the Fermi level. So, electrons can easily be excited to increase their momentum a bit and consequently move in one direction. Now if you add one electron to the wire, the Fermi level rises. However, you would not be able to see the increase caused by one single electron (or a couple thousand for that matter). The conductivity of the metal is only affected if you raise the Fermi level so that the band gets completely filled, i.e. you now have a band gap and thus a semiconductor or insulator. Or, the slope of the conduction band at the Fermi level gets altered significantly. You thus affect the conductivity of your metal which still stays a metal.

In practice, I don't think it would be feasible to see any such effects just by "adding" electrons. You would have to ensure they do not flow off the wire and for example into the battery that provides your electric field..

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra electrons isn't going to make any difference, at least as a first approximation.

Suppose we have a wire with some applied voltage $V$ and some current flowing $I$. What this means is that the power supply is injecting $I/e$ electrons per second into one end of the wire and extracting $I/e$ electrons from the other end of the wire. The resistance is determined by the mobility of the electrons in the wire i.e. how frequently they scatter off whetever the wire is made of.

If you add a bit of extra charge to the wire there's no reason to think it would change the electron mobility - charging metals doesn't make any measurable change to their resistivity. You still have $I/e$ electrons per second entering and leaving the wire and the mobility of those electrons is still the same.

Comment: What if we add a lot of extra charge to the wire?

Comment: You cannot add very much extra charge to the wire. An extra charges you add go to surface of the conductor so the surface charge density quickly builds to the point where [field emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission) starts and the charge leaks off again. The effect on the resisitivity is likely to be immeasurably small.

Comment: Why do the extra charges go to the surface of the conductor? Can't they stay within the conduction band and be driven by the electric field?

Comment: @Gatz': [see this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=charge+conductor+surface)